# Make an unclickable Menu Item

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

I'm doing a `Dropdown` menu using Ant Design:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Icon, Dropdown, Menu } from "antd";
const { Item } = Menu;

class NotificationBell extends Component {
    render() {
        const menu = (
            <Menu>
                <Item><p>You must be connected to get notifications.</p></Item>
            </Menu>
        );
        return (
            <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={['click']}>
                <Icon type="bell" theme="outlined" />
            </Dropdown>
        );
    }
}
```

Ant this is what I get:

[image: Ant Design Dropdown]

But I don't want to just remove the highlight, I also want to make the component unclickable, i.e. instead of a "hand cursor" I want a "normal cursor".

Adding the `selectable={false}` prop on the `Menu` component as suggested by [the Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu) doesn't help. What should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation you linked](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu.Item) to specifies a `disabled` prop on `Menu.Item` which may or may do what you want. If you want to do something other than what the library provides, you can customize the behavior.

You can use the CSS property `cursor` to specify which cursor you want on hover.

You might want to use `not-allowed` for a disabled-style cursor, or the default arrow: `default`.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

For future reference, you can't prevent a user from clicking on the element. What you want to do is actually to communicate the affordance (or lack thereof) using visual cues, and potentially alter the behavior of your application when receiving that input.

Comment: And as for disabling the highlighting?

Comment: Again, just override the CSS. It's probably a background color, and you can check which element it's on with the web inspector.

Comment: Ok thank you, I wondered if there was a solution directly with Ant Design, like a prop I didn't know about, but apparently not.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi I'm not familiar with it; I updated my answer to include what's in the docs you linked, but I don't know if it does or doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

The CSS property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) set to `none` makes the component ignore mouse events without altering the style of the cursor.

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.Item key="/">
    <Link href="/">Clickable</Link>
  </Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
    Unclickable
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>here
```